# how to pull images from a folder with jquery?

Tags: php, jquery

I'm using this code in `index.php`

```
<?php
    $filepath ="images/topbanner";
    $files =scandir($filepath);

    if ($handle = opendir($filepath)) {

        echo '<div>';
        while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
            if($entry != '.' && $entry != '..'){

        ?>
            <img src="<?=$filepath.'/'.$entry?>" />
        <?php
            }
        }   

        echo '<div>';
        closedir($handle);
    }   
?>
```

But I wanted to know that can I pull the images from a folder with jquery?

If not possible with jquery: how can I embed this code not in `index.php` but in `slider.js` that is in js file.

Comment: There is the File API, but that is not completely supported by all browsers. Any chance you could build a web service that would enumerate all the files in the folder? That would be a common option.

Comment: You should use AJAX, PHP with jQuery. This will accomplish you task

Answer (score 1):

**"I wanted to know that can I pull the images from a folder with jquery?"**

JavaScript that runs in the browser does not have 
access to either a local or server-based file system.

You need to use PHP for this.

Maybe you can pass an array of URL from PHP to JS/jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `AJAX, PHP with jQuery`. This will accomplish you task.

It's not possible to work with server directory(folder) with alone jQuery or Javascript since they only work at client browser.

- Use jquery/Javascript for your user interaction
- Allow AJAX as middle ware to make new `HTTP server call` to your server `index.php`
- Then write script with PHP in index.php to handle your task.
- server will response back through AJAX to your client
- Now finally, handle the response with jquery/javascript

That's all

Lear AJAX, PHP

**javascript - Client side**

**PHP - Server Side**

(AJAX make dynamic interaction with Client browser and Server)